# Partner Community Users cannot create record - Insufficient Privileges

Tags: community, leads, insufficient-privileges

I have set up Partner Communities in my Salesforce org. I have my new 'communities user' profile which I have granted access to a community partner user to Create /Edit Leads. I have also granted access to lead record types.

I have set up an Account as a Partner, with a Contact which I enabled as a partner. I log in to the community as the new partner contact which is fine. When I go to the Leads tab, and try and create a new lead, I get the 'insufficient privileges' error.

I have also tested with other objects and the same thing happens. Since I do not believe that this is the settings on the partner user profile, I cannot figure out what is causing this. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your new lead page a VF page?

Comment: No. It is a standard page.

Comment: Do you have any triggers that fire on lead insert?

Comment: Are you viewing the page in the community with the community base URL?

Comment: There is no triggers firing and yes it is in community base url - https://full-partners.cs7.force.com/00Q/o (It is in Full Sandbox also)