# Can a customer community user create a new detail record?

Tags: apex, security, customer-community

We have a customer community user and want the user to be able to create a master-detail record for different kinds of objects. However, everytime we try to insert a new record we get the following error:

> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

I understand that this is an access issue to a field the user does not have access to but I have verified that the user has access to all the fields required. So I think it is because customer community or partner community user cannot create a master-detail record. Does anyone have any experience with this?

I found a similar issue that has been left unanswered [Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70969/partner-community-users-cannot-create-record-insufficient-privileges).

Comment: does the user profile have create permission on the CRUD for the detail records ?

Comment: Yes. Full access to object, and fields and read access to the master.

Comment: This is definitely not connected to type of connection object has. Are the detail is one of standard objects? 
If trigger or workflow on insert from detail object is updating other fields / objects they should have access there as well.

Comment: There are no triggers or workflows. Standard objects cannot be a detail in a master detail relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Master detail relationship has a setting that specifies what kind of access to master record can create, delete, edit detail records. The user with read only access can only do dml on detail records, if the setting is set to "read Only".[image]

Answer (score 0):

for Standard profiles you can not control CRUD permission. you can do:
1. Clone the standard profile.
2. Give permissions on the custom objects which are used in the community.

Try it!

Let me know if you need some more info.